# How to convert acceleration and velocity

Tags: velocity, acceleration

I have acceleration pulse data.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Time': [-0.05,-0.049,-0.048,-0.047,-0.046,-0.045,-0.044,-0.043,-0.042,-0.041,-0.04,-0.039,-0.038,-0.037,-0.036,-0.035,-0.034,-0.033,-0.032,-0.031,-0.03,-0.029,-0.028,-0.027,-0.026,-0.025,-0.024,-0.023,-0.022,-0.021,-0.02,-0.019,-0.018,-0.017,-0.016,-0.015,-0.014,-0.013,-0.012,-0.011,-0.01,-0.009,-0.008,-0.007,-0.006,-0.005,-0.004,-0.003,-0.002,-0.001,0,0.001,0.002,0.003,0.004,0.005,0.006,0.007,0.008,0.009,0.01,0.011],
    'Acc': [-6.274794952,-8.411628382,-8.008585651,-4.247482683,-11.41527723,-17.88328712,-20.73880394,-30.70689943,-38.64880814,-37.2218402,-24.52480615,-11.4554172,-5.676814858,-14.39142125,-25.53694018,-32.11794217,-40.10451,-40.11716753,-38.14494162,-34.95303719,-29.0614066,-34.81435931,-31.10463242,-34.78288131,-40.1554556,-35.79119476,-30.33483666,-25.05780838,-24.08511046,-27.40379303,-28.14228017,-27.58239841,-26.89127685,-23.65842224,-24.85247144,-28.90349477,-23.89934868,-14.15168395,-12.32396259,-15.84089578,-17.97792317,-13.97623975,-10.99732079,-9.96130313,-7.160783784,-6.884257627,-7.402375505,-4.32898903,-3.503247759,-4.444464077,-6.198176174,-7.345642122,-8.44697406,-9.481825989,-6.627226153,-5.531679922,-5.980458682,-7.755558808,-4.62286857,0.815913801,2.308059709,2.404857118]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

If you integrate over time, the speed comes out as follows.

```
vel=
[-6.274794952,-6.283206580382,-6.291215166033,-6.295462648716,-6.306877925946,-6.324761213066,-6.345500017006,-6.376206916436,-6.41485572457599,-6.45207756477599,-6.47660237092599,-6.48805778812599,-6.49373460298399,-6.50812602423399,-6.53366296441399,-6.56578090658399,-6.60588541658399,-6.64600258411399,-6.68414752573399,-6.71910056292399,-6.74816196952399,-6.782976328834,-6.814080961254,-6.848863842564,-6.88901929816399,-6.92481049292399,-6.95514532958399,-6.98020313796399,-7.00428824842399,-7.03169204145399,-7.05983432162399,-7.08741672003399,-7.11430799688399,-7.13796641912399,-7.16281889056399,-7.19172238533399,-7.21562173401399,-7.22977341796399,-7.24209738055399,-7.25793827633399,-7.27591619950399,-7.28989243925399,-7.30088976004399,-7.31085106317399,-7.31801184695799,-7.32489610458499,-7.33229848008999,-7.33662746911999,-7.34013071687899,-7.34457518095599,-7.35077335712999,-7.35811899925199,-7.36656597331199,-7.37604779930099,-7.38267502545399,-7.38820670537599,-7.39418716405799,-7.40194272286599,-7.40656559143599,-7.40574967763499,-7.40344161792599,-7.40103676080799]
```

However, when integrated over time, the result is as follows.

How can I manipulate it to get something like the graph below?

(The hint is 56.3kph, so set 56.3/3.6 as the initial speed.)

I do not know.

```
answer_vel=
[16.722416714519,16.715073502852,16.7068633958355,16.7007353616685,16.692903981712,16.678254699537,16.658943654007,16.633220802322,16.598542948537,16.560607624367,16.529734301192,16.511744189517,16.503178073488,16.493143955434,16.473179774719,16.444352333544,16.408241107459,16.368130268694,16.328999214119,16.292450224714,16.260443002819,16.228505119864,16.195545623999,16.162601867134,16.125132698679,16.087159373499,16.054096357789,16.026400035269,16.001828575849,15.976084124104,15.948311087504,15.920448748214,15.893211910584,15.867937061039,15.843681614199,15.816803631094,15.790402209369,15.771376693054,15.758138869784,15.744056440599,15.727147031124,15.711169949664,15.698683169394,15.688203857434,15.679642813977,15.6726202932715,15.6654769767055,15.659611294438,15.6556951760435,15.6517213201255,15.6464,15.639628090852,15.631731782761,15.6227673827365,15.6147128566655,15.608633403628,15.602877334326,15.596009325581,15.589820111892,15.5879166345075,15.5894786212625,15.591835079676]
```

How do I integrate to get that value?